# Set Active / Foreground window from PID

Tags: python, subprocess, pywin32

I am trying to set a program (known PID) to the top / active /foreground (not sure which is most appropriate).

The PID is set to the windows process PID

```
    handle = win32api.OpenProcess( win32con.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,
                        False, pid)
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(handle)
    win32gui.SetActiveWindow(handle)
```

I either get:

```
    pywintypes.error: (1400, 'SetForegroundWindow', 'Invalid window Handle.')

    pywintypes.error: (1400, 'SetActiveWindow', 'Invalid window handle.')
```

I realize it is a problem in the handler but im not sure how I am supposed to properly get the working handle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This job can be done by pywinauto:

```
from pywinauto import Application
app = Application().connect(process=<pid>)
app.top_window().set_focus()
```

But it may not work for minimized app.

Answer (score 3):

## OpenProcess function:

If the function succeeds, the return value is an open handle to the specified process.and it can be used in any function that requires a handle to a process.

## SetForegroundWindow function:

parameters of it is a handle to the window that should be activated and brought to the foreground.

so you need a translate like this:

```
HWND h = ::GetTopWindow(0 );
while ( h )
{
  DWORD pid;
  DWORD dwTheardId = ::GetWindowThreadProcessId( h,&pid);
         if ( pid == /*your process id*/ )
         {
              // here h is the handle to the window
              break;
         }
         h = ::GetNextWindow( h , GW_HWNDNEXT);
}
```

a python version:

```
def find_window_for_pid(pid):
    result = None
    def callback(hwnd, _):
        nonlocal result
        ctid, cpid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
        if cpid == pid:
            result = hwnd
            return False
        return True
    win32gui.EnumWindows(callback, None)
    return result
```

some note:

> But note that this can easily fail, because when you first launch the process, it probably doesn't have a window until a few milliseconds later. Without some means of synchronizing between the parent and child, there's really no way around this. (You can hack it by, say, sleeping for a second, but that has the same problem as any attempt to sleep instead of synchronizing—most of the time, it'll be way too long, reducing the responsiveness/performance of your code for no reason, and occasionally, when the computer is busy, it'll be too short and fail.)

The only way to really solve this is to use pywin32 to create the process instead of using standard Python code. Then you have a handle to the process. This means you can wait for the child to start its window loop, then enumerate just that process's windows.

Comment: Do you have a python example?